# Fixed table width and scrollable table row

Tags: html, css

I managed to get the scrollable table working (table as a whole), but now I want to make it a fixed size and scroll only within the table rows.

Lets say I have a normal table of a width 100.

```
<table width="100">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This will work fine, how ever if the value inside of `<td>` is really long

```
<td>LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLong</td>
```

the table width will be increased to accommodate that long `<td>`

What I am trying to accomplish is to make the `<tr>` scrollable.
So if the `<td>` within the `<tr>` is really long one, the `<tr>` should become scrollable, instead of increasing the whole table width.

I got some partial solution by making the td scrollable. But I want to make `tr` scrollable instead of `td`

```
<table width="100">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>

  <td width="50">
   <div style="width: 50px; overflow: auto">   
   JanuaryJanuaryJanuaryJanuaryJanuary
     </div>
</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: cant you eliminate `table` and use `display:table` with `div`?

Comment: if you made your tr scroll, how would the tds know what width to be? you would end up with your columns not aligning properly under your headings so you cannot use a table for this sort of thing.  What I think you should do instead is let the table be as wide as it wants to be and put it in a div and have overflow on that instead

Answer (score 0):

Creating a scroll element on an `<html>` block is pretty simple. try adding the following to the `<tr>`

(CSS)

```
tr {
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

to create a better view in your `<td>` elements you could add:

(CSS)

```
td {
word-break: break-word;
}
```

Hope this helps!